# Hybrid graphic driver nvidia low resolution mode. and wine not working

Tags: graphics, wine, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I m new to ubuntu. I have `Dell Inspiron 3442` with dual graphics `Intel Haswell` and `Nvidia 820m`. I installed `Nvidia 352 driver prime` along with `xorg` that came installed by default. At some times after startup it shows running in low graphic mode and i just restart it. How can i solve this problem?
I also tried downloading wine and it showed dependencies cant be resolved. Also tried these apt-get commands,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

but nothing seems to work. Is it also because of graphics driver?

Comment: thanks for reply.i am using ubuntu 14.04. the error while running these commands are 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me make something clear, the problems you encounter while installing wine and those of graphics card are totally two different problems. Let's sort out your problems with wine installation first.

From what it seems your wine has some problems with dependencies,

**Make sure** you didn't add some custom repositories or `ppas`, if you did remove them from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then do following,

Remove wine completely

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then, solve existing dependency problems

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Now once your dependencies are sorted you should get your graphics drivers sorted out, If you have hybrid graphics you will have to choose which graphics card to use, in your case i would suggest `Nvidia` rather than `intel`. Luis Alvarado has already written a very comprehensive guide for installing graphics driver in ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers), Check it out and set up your display drivers.

After that is done, you will want to reinstall wine to play games or install windows softwares, to do that, type in,

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

It should install without any problems.